# IE9 does not show navigation menu when Maximised but does when "restored Down" to a certain size

Tags: internet-explorer-9, screen-resolution, navigationbar

I have created a website and hosted it in a Google gadget for Google Sites and it works fine in FF, Chrome and Safari with a multitude of resolutions. However when in IE9, the navigation bar does not display when the browser is maximized. If you restore down and bring the width in a bit, it shows, expanding out again and it disappears. I can't work out why. Using a tool I have established that it works on 1024x768 resolution, but not on 1280x800 or higher.

[Here's a link to the Website](https://sites.google.com/a/consultcambridge.com/consultcambridge/expertise):

P.S. the links to the navigation will not work as site is not 'live'.